# IP/GRE compiled in kernel but gre0 interface doesnt exist

Tags: linux, tunneling, iproute2, gre

Im trying to create IP over GRE tunnel but i get No such device:

```
ip tunnel add gre0 mode gre remote 192.168.152.22 local 192.168.152.21 ttl 255
ioctl: No such device
```

I have compiled GRE support in my kernel:

```
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_DEMUX=y
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE=y
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_BROADCAST=y
```

There is no `gre0` interface when interfaces are displayed via `ifconfig -a` though i see all available network interfaces (also those not upped yet).

My kernel version is `2.6.30.9` and `iproute2` version is `2-2.6.33`.

EDIT:  `ip tunnel show` displays:

```
ip tunnel show
ioctl: Invalid argument
tunl0: ip/ip  remote any  local any  ttl inherit  nopmtudisc
sit0: ipv6/ip  remote any  local any  ttl 64  nopmtudisc 6rd-prefix 2002::/16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was GRE demultiplexer module required by ip_gre. When kernel loads GRE demultiplexer driver registers protocol 47 handle so when ip_gre.c attempted to do the same it fails because it has been registered before. It is solved by modifying ip_gre.c to not register protocol GRE handle.